# Ruby readlines is not assigning to variable during rspec test

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a simple program to generate a text file, and i'm writing rspec tests to check certain lines in the file to make sure they are correct.

So i'm storing the lines of the file in @file array and indexing it to check my results:

```
# Fizzbuzz

it "returns 'bazz' for 100th element" do
  file_path = File.expand_path("../fbb.txt", File.dirname(__FILE__))
  #debugger
  #puts file_path
  @file = File.readlines(file_path)
  expect(@file[99].strip).to eq("Bazz")
end
```

Now when i leave the debugger commented, I get `undefined method "strip" for nil:NilClass`.  However, if I comment in the debugger, and do nothing besides type `c` for continue, then my rspec test passes.

It's almost as if the filepath does not get loaded in time for the readlines function.  When puts'ing the file_path however, it appears correct.

Comment: Are you creating fbb.txt in the test setup?  If so, please show that code as well.

Comment: Did you try putsing @file before expect? By the way you can use just local variable not instance.

Comment: Try to set absolute `file_path` like _/tmp/fbb.txt_

Comment: @infused No, the file is already created prior to testing.

Comment: @Aleksey Yes, it returns an empty array.  the iv's are from when I was trying to use before(:each).

Comment: @cema-sp Tried using absolute path, still doesn't work.

Comment: @KMongiello have you ever tried **Pry** ? With it, you always could insert `binding.pry` just before `expect` and get an interactive console on the test run. It always helps me.